# Java: This method must return a result type of type double

Tags: java, methods, return, double

i've been stuck on this code for about an hour and i just can't find a sollution for this.
If anyone can help me i'd be really thankful.
Thanks in advance.

```
public double  berekenPrijs(int aantalBallen) {
    if (aantalBallen == 0) {
        return  0.80;
    }
    else if(aantalBallen == 1 ){
        return 0.80;
    }
    else if (aantalBallen <= 3 && aantalBallen >=2) {
        return 0.9 * aantalBallen * 0.80;
```

Comment: This does not seem to a complete method. Can you share the complete method and the result as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public class Goovy123 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(berekenPrijs(0));
        System.out.println(berekenPrijs(1));
        System.out.println(berekenPrijs(2));
        System.out.println(berekenPrijs(3));
    }

    static public double berekenPrijs(int aantalBallen) {
        if (aantalBallen == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if (aantalBallen == 1) {
            return 0.80;
        } else if (aantalBallen <= 3 && aantalBallen >= 2) {
            return 0.9 * aantalBallen * 0.80;
        }
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

**Sample run:**

```
0.0
0.8
1.4400000000000002
2.16
```

Comment: I suggest returning a fixed value, preferably a NaN, from the final return statement. That will lead to easier debug if it is ever called with an unexpected value.

Answer (score 1):

If aantalBallen is not 0, 1, between 2 and 3, what does your function return?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a return statement after the last elseIf block as well.

That return statement will be used to return double from this method when aantalBallen is not equal to 0 , 1 or <= 3 and >=2.

As no matter what even if all the conditions fail, the method needs to return a value in this case a Double.